# Get all objects that has same enum value as an instance object's enum value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum colors: {blue: 0, red: 1}
end

my_car.color # => "blue"
```

How do I get all cars with the same enum value as a certain object? I.e. in the case above, all blue cars.

This is my best bet so far:

```
Car.public_send(my_car.color)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all cars with the same color as `my_car`:

```
Car.where(color: my_car.color)
```

Or if that doesn't work:

```
Car.where(color: Car.colors[my_car.color])
```

Comment: This appears to not work actually, even if it syntaxically should.

Comment: I have added another possibility.